# Python: subclass or metaclass for an ordered collection of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python.
I want to make a collection of dictionaries, with some of my own methods. This question is two part:

1. should I use a list or a dictionary as the template for this container?
2. how would I implement this? I have read on stack overflow various answers for this suggesting using `collection.MutableSequence` or list, etc.

   ```
   class OrderedSetOfDictionaries(<something>):
     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       <maybe super().__init__()>

     <do I have to redefine methods if I do not wish to change their behavior>
   ```

---

Example of desired data structure

```
ordered_set_of_dictionaries = 
{
  "dictionary_1" : {
                      "key_1": value_1,
                      "key_2": value_2,
                      <etc>
                    },
  "dictionary_2" : {
                      "key_1": value_1,
                      "key_2": value_2,
                      <etc>
                    },
  "dictionary_3" : {
                      "key_1": value_1,
                      "key_2": value_2,
                      <etc>
                    },
  <etc>

}
```

`ordered_set_of_dictionaries.last()`

--> `<dictionary_n>`

`ordered_set_of_dictionaries["dictionary_1"]["key_1"]`

--> `value_1`

etc

Comment: Subclassing built-in types is rarely necessary. I suggest that you write a class that contains a list of whatever as an attribute: prefer aggregation to inheritance.

Comment: An example of what you want to achieve would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it by subclassing OrderedDict. As well as a `last()` function I also added `first()` and `ith(i)` functions. `ith(i)` operates similar to list indexing.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class ord_dict_with_indexing(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(ord_dict_with_indexing, self).__init__(*args)

    def ith(self, i):
        return self.__getitem__(list(self.keys())[i])

    def last(self):
        return self.ith(-1)

    def first(self):
        return self.ith(0)
```

For example:

```
d = ord_dict_with_indexing()
d["dictionary_1"] = {"key_1":"value_1","key_2":"value_2"}
d["dictionary_2"] = {"key_3":"value_3","key_4":"value_4"}
d["dictionary_3"] = {"key_5":"value_1","key_2":"value_5"}

>>> d.first()
{'key_1': 'value_1', 'key_2': 'value_2'}
>>> d.last()
{'key_2': 'value_5', 'key_5': 'value_1'}
>>> d.ith(1)
{'key_3': 'value_3', 'key_4': 'value_4'}
>>> d['dictionary_1']['key_1']
'value_1'
```

Note that the order will appear in the order that the elements are added.